# Route alias not working in jest, using Next.js with Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, jestjs, alias

I am working on a Next.js App (v13.2.3) that is using Typescript. I have a path alias configured in `tsconfig.json`. Any idea on how I can make the jest environment aware of the path alias?

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I have followed these instructions exactly on adding jest to the project:
https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#setting-up-jest-with-the-rust-compiler

The ecosystem is operating correctly, except any file where I am using the path alias defined in `tsconfig.json`, the test will fail with the warning: `Cannot find module '@/example/file' from 'src/pages/index.tsx'.

```
//jest.config.js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const customJestConfig = {
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],

  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by updating `jest.config.js` to the following:

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```